# Vertex groups get deleted/are missing when I reopen the project?

Tags: vertices

I tried rigging the character and weight painting the rig on the mesh. After I save the project and reopen it, the vertex groups are missing, but the armature modifier is there and the bones are in the position and named properly. I tried this with other projects that are created with the same Blender version, and the vertex groups get permanently deleted even if they were there before.

Comment: Did you change Blender versions from saving vs. opening?  Can you provide a file, along with *exact* steps to reproduce the problem, along with exact versions of Blender used to follow those steps?  If you get my attention and provide a file and exact steps, I will at the least see if I can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Not sure how to share this. After a bit of testing, what happens is that when i open blender, attach armature to an object and add vertex groups, then close the project and reopen it, the project doesn't have the vertex groups. Now if I add them again to the same project and save again and reopen, then they are there. This is happening with each version I tried(2.9,3.0,3.1,3.3,3.4).

Comment: Then the file would be the file in the state immediately before "attach armature to an object".  You would want to detail some of those steps for reproducing the problem-- for example, *how* did you attach armature to object?  Parent with automatic weights, something else?  *How* did you add vertex groups, and which vertex groups?  And don't forget to mention that you saved the file, because that'd be a clear reason for your problems :)  Then we can follow your exact steps, with your exact file, and see if it goes wrong for us, and possibly see *why* it goes wrong.